# How does one reference a provider defined through a string token using @ViewChild in Angular 9, using the string token as a selector?

Tags: angular

According to the Angular documentation for the [`@ViewChild` decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild), one of the supported selectors is a provider with a string token. However when I define a provider using a string token in a child component and try and reference it using the `@ViewChild` decorator the view query is undefined.

I know it's possible to reference the provider using the `read` property with the component it's registered in as a selector, but how do I reference it using the string token as a selector alone?

I'm specifically talking about this type of string token selector (not a class provider, template reference variable, component, directive or a `TemplateRef`):

> Any provider defined through a string token (e.g. `@ViewChild('someToken') someTokenVal: any`)

Here's an example:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<h1>Child</h1>`,
  providers: [{ provide: 'Token', useValue: 'Value' }]
})

export class ChildComponent{}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `<app-child></app-child>`
})

export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild('Token') childToken: string;

  ngAfterViewinit(){
    console.log('token: ', childToken);
  }
}
```

This logs:

```
token: undefined
```

Comment: I think that is a regression in Ivy. It should work with ViewEngine if you disable Ivy.

Comment: Thanks, @yurzui. I think I'll try it out.

Comment: You were right @yurzui. It is a regression. It works if I disable Ivy. Thank you. I've answered the question but if you'd like, you could answer it and I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you again.

Comment: That's ok. I don't mind if you have already answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui) had mentioned this is a regression in Ivy. This will not work. If you want to use a string token provider as a selector in `@ViewChild` you need to disable Ivy in the ***tsconfig.json*** file.

```
{
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false,
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `ViewChild('stringToken')` where stringToken is a template ref, not a selector

```
<div #stringToken></div>
```

also you can reference it by component or directive

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child
```

in your case

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think you've misunderstood my question. In the first example you've given, `#stringToken` is a template reference variable selector and in the second, it is the component selector. I'm specifically talking about a provider registered in the child component using a string token. I'm trying to reference the `Token` provider in the child component providers using the `Token` string token as a selector. Thank you though. It's a very specific use case. I think I found a bug and I'm trying to fix it as an OS contribution.